# laravel 5.2 page url is changed but view isn't loaded

Tags: php, laravel

I want to go create.php If user click button that not logged in user redirect to login page in index.blade.php.

But only page URL is changed. Here's my codes.

index.blade.php

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button" aria-expanded="false" onclick="location.href='{{ route('board.create') }}' ">글쓰기</button>
```

Route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
Route::get('board/create', ['as' => 'board.create', 'uses' =>'BoardController@create']);
});
```

Controller

```
public function create() {

    return view('board.create');

}
```

View create.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
.......
@endsection
```

Comment: try return View::make('board.create');

Comment: you should have this file `resources/views/board/create.blade.php`

Comment: `resources/views/board/create.blade.php` is exist. And try return View::make('board.create') is not working T.T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you need to redirect user into login page if not logged in otherwise redirect to create page. With this, Please check below button with `if` statement. You just need to replace my below snippet at your `index.blade.php`

```
@if(Auth::user())
   <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button" aria-expanded="false" onclick="location.href='{{ route('board.create') }}' ">글쓰기</button>
@else
   <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button" aria-expanded="false" onclick="location.href='{{ url('/login') }}' ">글쓰기</button>
@endif
```

Let me know you have any query OR I'm wrong here.

Comment: I tried same of yours, `<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button" aria-expanded="false" onclick="location.href='{{ route('board.create') }}' ">글쓰기</button>` this part work nothing. changed URL only..

Comment: No worries!, Could you please check your mysql error log?

Comment: I check developer tool, It's definitely create.blade.php , but contents of create.blade.php is  same of index.blade.php

Comment: I think view file is loaded successfully

Comment: Yup, any error here? If you don't mind, I need to check your that code..

Comment: Have you checked [laravel default debugger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30012021/laravel-5-enable-laravel-debugbar). This may help you to check and solve this hidden error.

Comment: Hmm. I can't see any invisible erros.

Comment: Mark comment your `board.create` route and replace same with below:

`Route::get('board.create', function() {
echo 'HERE!';
return 'Returning a simple string without any View rendering.';
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126627/discussion-between-addweb-solution-pvt-ltd-and-).