# barryvdh/laravel-debugbar does not appear in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpdebugbar

Please let me assert: This question is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30012021/laravel-5-enable-laravel-debugbar),

In Laravel 5  I am trying to install `barryvdh/laravel-debugbar`. but it  is not showing.

I did the following:

Installation:

`composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar`

Added the following lines to the config/app.php in the providers section

`'Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider',`

And in the facades list..

`'Debugbar' => 'Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade',`
Further I execute:

`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider"`

After that I tried everything in answers to a similar SO question I mentioned at the beginning of this question.

Like enabling debug in `.env`, enable it in the debugbar.php,
clearing config cache with `php artisan config:clear`

and caching again with

`php artisan config:cache`

also .. 
`php artisan view:clear`;

But the debug bar won't appear?

What could be the reasons?

Comment: Check your `APP_ENV` if it is `local`. `Production` might be causing the issue.

Comment: What did you set your environment to in the .env?

Comment: some time due to `autoload` files. Have you tried `sudo composer dumpautoload` ?

Comment: app environment is local in `.env`

Comment: @SagarGautam, though I did a sudo composer dumpautoload, and it did not work,  your suggestion was not very good.. It gave a warning not to run composer with root permissions..

Comment: any other reasons

Comment: set debug = true in your .env file

Comment: it's already set to true

Answer (score 8):

maybe you ‍‍`cache` all `routes` in laravel.
please clear route cache:

```
PHP artisan route:clear
```

please see the below link:

[When route caching is enabled, the debugbar fails to render](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/pull/287)

Answer (score 5):

If the dev environment of your laravel project is using the default configuration of Apache for web root directory, make sure the `AllowOverride All` is set for the web root directory.

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
   ...
   AllowOverride All 
   ...
</Directory>
```

Restart web service and try reloading the page. The debug bar should be showing up properly.

Comment: for my case bar appears on 404 pages only but not showing on other pages.

Answer (score 1):

I found the debugbar stopped working when I ran following.

```
composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
```

In this case, the Debugbar wont show even the `APP_ENV` is `local` or anything other than production. I believe only marking `APP_ENV` as `local` is enough to activate debugbar.

What I did here, by executing following.

`composer install` and `php artisan route:cache`

Answer (score 1):

In my situation, there was an issue with the creation permissions for the debugbar directory, which was resolved by creating and granting the appropriate permissions to this directory.

in your project directory run:

```
mkdir storage/debugbar
chmod -R 777 storage/debugbar
```

Answer (score 0):

Set APP_DEBUG=true in .env file in the root folder of the Laravel application.

Answer (score 0):

If you checked all instructions in the github repo and the debugbar is still not working,
the problem may be in your NGINX/APACHE configuration.

In my case, nginx `conf` сontained the section:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.php /index.php?$args $fastcgi_script_name =404;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
}
```

You need to take out the try files directive to section:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri 
    $uri/ index.php /index.php?$args 
    $fastcgi_script_name = 404;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar --dev
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan debugbar:clear
php artisan vendor:publish
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that app environment is set to `local`:

```
APP_ENV=local
```

2. Make sure that app debug is enabled:

```
APP_DEBUG=true
```

3. Make sure that debugbar is enabled:

```
DEBUGBAR_ENABLED=true
```

4. Make sure to run the following commands:

```bash
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan debugbar:clear
```